# Designing a parallel algorithm for DDOS prevention?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, parallel-processing, distributed-computing

My multicore machine is receiving packets and distributes them evenly (sort-of round robin) among its cores. Each core should decide whether to let the packet pass or drop it, depending solely on its origin address.

I need to find lock-less algorithm and data structure to allow this. Can you help?

Comment: need more info - do you have a list of blocked ips?

Comment: Sounds interesting, but IMHO this question is far, far too broad. You should provide some details reg your technology stack.

Comment: @WeaselFox no. the purpose is to block a flood coming from a small group of addresses by blocking them, while allowing other addresses to pass.

Comment: @home it's an abstract question, the algorithm and data structure is what of interest.

Comment: @liorda: so you just need a IP whitelist for each process?

Comment: @home a separate IP blacklist will not suffice since I don't have control on packet distribution among cores. So if address IP1 is blocked on core 1, I need to "know" that while processing another packet from it on core 2, and block it.

Comment: So you need a global whitelist (or blacklist) shared across the processes?

Comment: @home yes, but then updating an entry would require locking it.

Comment: How about changing the question to: "I need a thread-safe lock-less collection"? Check the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace in .NET 4. If I got it right, everything else in your question is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are happy to use Java, or look at the design of Java source, you could chose a random key and then retrieve a queue from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html. Given the queue, you could add the packet to it without blocking if it was a http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html

Much of java.util.concurrent is due to Doug Lea, who has information on it at http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/concurrency-interest/index.html.

Possibly overkill for your particular problem, but might satisfy a general request for info on data structures in this area.